# 2010 Sante Fe, high beam on pass. side not working

Tags: hyundai, headlight, santa-fe

2010 Sante Fe, high beam on passenger side not working but all other lights work. Checked fuses all good. Put meter on connector to high beam, shows no power to that connector. Where would the break be?

Comment: Have you checked the fuses?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you swap the bulbs out just to absolutely make sure it's not the bulb?

Comment: Paulster cha'd bulbs first, then put meter on connector-no power to bulb, Howie-checked fuzes next all good.